# Acumatica: fields in extension became invisible after the upgrade of the Acumatica Framework 20.101.32.42

Tags: c#, asp.net, acumatica

We have extension class `MPCSCalendar : PXCacheExtension<CSCalendar>` that has fields:

```
    #region MonUnpaidTime
    public abstract class monUnpaidTime : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXDBInt]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Unpaid Break Time")]
    public virtual int? MonUnpaidTime { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region TueUnpaidTime
    public abstract class tueUnpaidTime : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXDBInt]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Unpaid Break Time")]
    public virtual int? TueUnpaidTime { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region WedUnpaidTime
    public abstract class wedUnpaidTime : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXDBInt]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Unpaid Break Time")]
    public virtual int? WedUnpaidTime { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region ThuUnpaidTime
    public abstract class thuUnpaidTime : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXDBInt]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Unpaid Break Time")]
    public virtual int? ThuUnpaidTime { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region FriUnpaidTime
    public abstract class friUnpaidTime : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXDBInt]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Unpaid Break Time")]
    public virtual int? FriUnpaidTime { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region SatUnpaidTime
    public abstract class satUnpaidTime : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXDBInt]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Unpaid Break Time")]
    public virtual int? SatUnpaidTime { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region SunUnpaidTime
    public abstract class sunUnpaidTime : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXDBInt]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Unpaid Break Time")]
    public virtual int? SunUnpaidTime { get; set; }
    #endregion
```

these fields didn't exist in parental class `CSCalendar` before the upgrade.
After the upgrade, `CSCalendar` has these fields:
[image]
The view looked like this before the upgrade:
[image]
How it looks now:
[image]
"Unpaid Break Time" columns dissipated now. No exceptions.

In ASPX before updated we used these fields with `px:PXTimeSpan` :

```
<px:PXTimeSpan CommitChanges="True" ID="edSunUnpaidTime" runat="server" DataField="SunUnpaidTime" InputMask="hh:mm" SuppressLabel="True" />
                <px:PXTimeSpan CommitChanges="True" ID="edMonUnpaidTime" runat="server" DataField="MonUnpaidTime" InputMask="hh:mm" SuppressLabel="True" />
                <px:PXTimeSpan CommitChanges="True" ID="edTueUnpaidTime" runat="server" DataField="TueUnpaidTime" InputMask="hh:mm" SuppressLabel="True" />
                <px:PXTimeSpan CommitChanges="True" ID="edWedUnpaidTime" runat="server" DataField="WedUnpaidTime" InputMask="hh:mm" SuppressLabel="True" />
                <px:PXTimeSpan CommitChanges="True" ID="edThuUnpaidTime" runat="server" DataField="ThuUnpaidTime" InputMask="hh:mm" SuppressLabel="True" />
                <px:PXTimeSpan CommitChanges="True" ID="edFriUnpaidTime" runat="server" DataField="FriUnpaidTime" InputMask="hh:mm" SuppressLabel="True" />
                <px:PXTimeSpan CommitChanges="True" ID="edSatUnpaidTime" runat="server" DataField="SatUnpaidTime" InputMask="hh:mm" SuppressLabel="True" />
```

Now in Acumatica ASPX file these fields used by `px:PXMaskEdit`:

```
 <px:PXMaskEdit Size="s" ID="edSunUnpaidTime" runat="server" DataField="SunUnpaidTime" SuppressLabel="True" Width="48" CommitChanges="true" />
                    <px:PXMaskEdit Size="s" ID="edMonUnpaidTime" runat="server" DataField="MonUnpaidTime" SuppressLabel="True" Width="48" CommitChanges="true" />
                    <px:PXMaskEdit Size="s" ID="edTueUnpaidTime" runat="server" DataField="TueUnpaidTime" SuppressLabel="True" Width="48" CommitChanges="true" />
                    <px:PXMaskEdit Size="s" ID="edWedUnpaidTime" runat="server" DataField="WedUnpaidTime" SuppressLabel="True" Width="48" CommitChanges="true" />
                    <px:PXMaskEdit Size="s" ID="edThuUnpaidTime" runat="server" DataField="ThuUnpaidTime" SuppressLabel="True" Width="48" CommitChanges="true" />
                    <px:PXMaskEdit Size="s" ID="edFriUnpaidTime" runat="server" DataField="FriUnpaidTime" SuppressLabel="True" Width="48" CommitChanges="true" />
                    <px:PXMaskEdit Size="s" ID="edSatUnpaidTime" runat="server" DataField="SatUnpaidTime" SuppressLabel="True" Width="48" CommitChanges="true" />
```

Intuition says me that I need to remove my fields with the same name from extension and use my Acumatica fields from `CSCalendar`, but it doesn't work and these fields are invisible.
Another solution is to rename my `XXXUnpaidTime` to `XXXUnpaidTime1` and create my own fields, it will work I suppose, but I don't believe it is proper solution.

I'm confirming: when I renamed these fields in extension - the issue resolved:

```
   #region MonUnpaidTime
    public abstract class monUnpaidTimeAp : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXDBInt()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Unpaid Break Time")]
    public virtual int? MonUnpaidTimeAp { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region TueUnpaidTime
    public abstract class tueUnpaidTimeAp : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXDBInt()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Unpaid Break Time")]
    public virtual int? TueUnpaidTimeAp { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region WedUnpaidTime
    public abstract class wedUnpaidTimeAp : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXDBInt()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Unpaid Break Time")]
    public virtual int? WedUnpaidTimeAp { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region ThuUnpaidTime
    public abstract class thuUnpaidTimeAp : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXDBInt()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Unpaid Break Time")]
    public virtual int? ThuUnpaidTimeAp { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region FriUnpaidTime
    public abstract class friUnpaidTimeAp : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXDBInt()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Unpaid Break Time")]
    public virtual int? FriUnpaidTimeAp { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region SatUnpaidTime
    public abstract class satUnpaidTimeAp : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXDBInt()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Unpaid Break Time")]
    public virtual int? SatUnpaidTimeAp { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region SunUnpaidTime
    public abstract class sunUnpaidTimeAp : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXDBInt()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Unpaid Break Time")]
    public virtual int? SunUnpaidTimeAp { get; set; }
    #endregion
```

[image]

But I don't like this solution.

I looks like Acumatica implemented UnpaidTime feature for their clients and that should be standard solution for such situation, where I customers of the framework should split existing extension with new Acumatica solution of the same issue. 
Should be proper, standard and elegant solution.

I will be grateful for any help or advice!

Comment: Check the code if they're being hidden explicitly depending on the settings e.g. SetVisible  etc.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but that is the first thing that I have checked.

Comment: @Mr.B customized fields should always start with the Usr prefix in order to not coincide with potential new fields from Acumatica, and in order to not affect their data during upgrades.

Comment: I believe, Acumatica implemented our existed extension, but still unclear why they just ignore our fields without exception/warning etc.